# Wine not installing, no matter what

Tags: apt, software-installation, wine, dpkg

Alright guys, here's the deal. 
I'm on ubuntu 14.04 xfce version, running on an Acer C270 Chromebook with crouton. This is a clean install of Ubuntu, not upgraded from a previous version, nor did it ever have any other version of wine on it.

I'm trying to install Wine. These are the commands I've used and all the solutions I've tried already to always the exact same result.

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

To success of adding the wine ppa

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get update
```

Also successful

```
   (trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And this is the problem. It seems fairly common so I google and find several solutions.
Installing only Wine1.7:

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.26-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.26-0ubuntu1~ppa1)
           Recommends: cups-bsd
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It would appear that I don't have i386 architecture right? So then I do this:

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$
```

That is all it outputs, so it would appear to be a success. So I do apt-get update. However installing wine1.7 again returns the same result.

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.26-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.26-0ubuntu1~ppa1)
           Recommends: cups-bsd
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I try to install cups-bsd and it sends me on a dependency goose chase

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install cups-bsd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups-bsd : Depends: cups-client (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install cups-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cups-client is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$
```

I also have tried installing wine1.7 and wine-i386 at the same time

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7 wine1.7-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.26-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: cups-bsd
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                              libglu1:i386
                     Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgphoto2-port10:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.22) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.26) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 1:0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libfontconfig:i386
                     Recommends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libgnutls26:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libtiff5:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libtiff4:i386 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxt6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: p11-kit-modules:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And here it is pointing to a bunch of libraries that I apparently don't have, also pointing back to an error with the dpkg multiarching so I also tried this fix:

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ gksu gedit /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Creating a text file with `foreign-architecture i386` printed in it to allow me to install wine1.7-i386. After successfully updating apt-get I try to install wine1.7-i386 and I get:

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                              libglu1:i386
                     Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgphoto2-port10:i386 (>= 2.5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.22) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.26) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 1:0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libfontconfig:i386
                     Recommends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libgnutls26:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libtiff5:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libtiff4:i386 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libxt6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: p11-kit-modules:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Once again.
Edit: I have confirmed that I do indeed have support for i386 architecture, because

```
sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

Returns i386 so that appears not to be the problem, very strange.

Even using the -f command with apt-get doesn't change anything

```
(trusty)pineapplez13@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install -f wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.26-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.26-0ubuntu1~ppa1)
           Recommends: cups-bsd
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also, using apt-get clean, apt-get autoclean, and apt-get -f install all return 0 packages modified in any way. Downloading through software center returns same result. 
I've tried what feels like every fix that has been uploaded as a solution to this problem but to no avail. This really doesn't wake any sense, I can't find out what the problem is.

Edit: I've now given up on installing wine, so I'm just going to try to build it in a 32-bit linux container. I'll post here with the steps I used if I ever get it working.

Comment: Same here, friend. Not only `wine` but some other cool libraries are not installing on my system. Been battling the problem for many weeks now. I guess I'll just have to do a re-install some day. :(

Answer (score 0):

First, clear your system with:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
```

Then remove Wine:

```
apt-get remove wine wine1.6
```

Then install only *one* package, depending on your system: either amd64 or i386

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

let me see your output of doing so in case of error.